# Selecting text and changing attributes bug?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am having trouble doing a simple text selection and change of attributes. I can't seem to get the program past the first step. It says that the `selectedRange` is nil. Why is this happening? Is this a bug with something?

```
func selectText() {
    if let textRange = textView?.selectedRange {
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)]
        textView.textStorage.addAttributes(attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], range: textRange)
    }
}
```

**Edit with code from @DionizB (not working)**

I call it from another Swift file that holds the view for the KeyboardAccessory. Code in that file is:

```
class KeyboardAccessory: UIView {
let VC = ViewController()
@IBAction func boldButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("boldButtonTapped -> Sending to bold()")
    VC.bold()
    }
}
```

Code now in main ViewController is:

```
var selectedRange: NSRange?

func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    selectedRange = textView.selectedRange
    print(selectedRange)
}

func bold() {
    print("Starting bold()")
    print(selectedRange)
    if let textRange = selectedRange {
        print(textRange)
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: UIFont.Weight.thin)]
        textView.textStorage.addAttributes(attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], range: textRange)
    }
}
```

textViewDidChangeSelection is printing the selectedRange but when bold() is called from the KeyboardAccessory View it prints nil! How I load the AccessoryView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textView.inputAccessoryView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("KeyboardAccessory", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView?
}
```

Comment: How do you access `KeyboardAccessory` and also this `let VC = ViewController()` creates a new instance of this `ViewController` which is different from the current one that you're accessing.

Comment: Okay. It's working if I make a new button on the page so it's something to do with the communication between. I've updated it with the code I put to load the AccessoryView. Thanks so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `viewDidLoad()` make sure you add `textView.delegate = self`. 
Also in your class inherit from `UITextViewDelegate`.

Then call your `selectText()` in `textViewDidChangeSelection(_:)`

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    selectText()
}
```

And it will work properly.

**EDIT**
Normally it should work even when you call your `selectText()` inside your button action. But since it's not working, let's do a workaround:
Declare `var selectedRange: NSRange?` in your class.

Then in

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    selectedRange = textView.selectedRange
}
```

And in your `selectText()` do this

```
func selectText() {
    if let textRange = selectedRange {
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)]
        textView.textStorage.addAttributes(attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any], range: textRange)
    }
}
```

**EDIT for AccessoryView**

Update your KeyboardAccessory:

```
class KeyboardAccessory: UIView {
    var boldAction: (() -> Void)? // This is a closure, give it a read after making your button work
    @IBAction func boldButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("boldButtonTapped -> Sending to bold()")
        boldAction?()
    }
}
```

Try to cast your loaded nib as KeyboardAccessory and access your action like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var keyboardAccessory = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("KeyboardAccessory", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! KeyboardAccessory?
    keyboardAccessory.boldAction = { [weak self] in // to avoid retain cycles, read also about these
        self?.selectText()
    }
    textView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardAccessory
}
```

Comment: Okay! I have the delegate declarations. I am trying to only change it when the user clicks a button. Example having a button that changes the selected text to bold. Do I need the textViewDidChangeSelection function?

Comment: Are you sure that your textView is not nil? Because I tried accessing you function inside a button action and the font was changed properly according to your method.

Comment: Yep, not nil. I printed - let textRange = textView?.selectedRange in textViewDidChangeSelection and it's printing the range. Does it need to be called inside that function? If so, how can I access it from my other func?

Comment: Still not working!!! ahhhhh. I added an update with some info. Something to do with calling the function from another Swift file?

Comment: It says (class KeyboardAccessory: UIView has no initialisers) & (var boldAction (() -> Void)? Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';')

Comment: Upss, I forgot `:` --> It should be `var boldAction: (() -> Void)? `

Comment: Should I somehow change my file structure? Instead of loading the view from nib is there a better way? I have multiple buttons I need to make...

Comment: Ok that worked!! :) Since I have multiple buttons though should I do it this way? Is there a better way of going about it?

Comment: This is the easiest one, then you might think of better approaches depending on your situation. Also don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :D